# Why is Google Colab using so much RAM when I try and convert .jpg files into an array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I am currently trying to load and convert images for training, but Colab uses all the RAM throughout this process before I even get to training. The block of code is below:

```
# 0=Angry, 1=Disgust, 2=Fear, 3=Happy, 4=Sad, 5=Surprise, 6=Neutral
classes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] # list of classes

IMG_SIZE = 224 # ImageNet => 224 x 224

# Read all images and convert them into an array
trainingData = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in classes:
        path = os.path.join(dataDirectory, category)
        class_num = classes.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                trainingData.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(trainingData)

features = []
labels = []

for feature, label in trainingData:
    features.append(feature)
    labels.append(label)

features = np.array(features).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3) # Convert to 4 Dimension

features = features/255.0 # Normalization before training

labels = np.array(labels)
```

I am utilizing Colab Pro. Any help or suggestions that could fix this would be appreciated!

Comment: How much memory does the process use, how many images are there, and how large are the images?

Comment: Hi @MichaelRuth. There are 28,709 images and the images are 48x48 (~1-3 KB each).  I am not sure how much memory the process utilizes.

Comment: Why don't you use `flow_image_from_directory`? It's a generator and it does not load all images once into the RAM

Comment: Then how do you know that it uses "so much RAM?" Either you know the memory usage and think it's too high, or you don't know how much memory is used. Also, the `IMG_SIZE` in your code is 224x224. Which is it: 48x48 or 224x224? 28,709 files averaging 2kB use ~58MB disk space, they will use much more memory as Python objects. If the image size is 224x224, this estimate increases to ~1.5GB.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRuth, thanks for the response. Colab tells me that I am exceeding the RAM limit (which is currently 25GB) and restarts runtime, so I would guess it's using above 25GB of memory.

Comment: Hi @Kaveh, I will try that out. Thanks!

Comment: It is simple to get a rough estimate of memory usage here. This requires about 28709 * 224 * 224 * 3 (overall number of pixels) * 4 (bytes per number in float32 representation) bytes, or more than 16GB. You are also duplicating everything as it exists once in the `trainingData` variable and once in the `features` array which will create a copy of the data -> 32GB already. There are several solutions, such as using smaller image size (why upsample 48x48 so much??), not loading everything into RAM at once, not copying the data/freeing memory using `del`.